# S3 Select Python error

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-s3-select

I'm trying to catch the data form a S3 object. I'm using  a S3 Select feature as below:

boto3 version : 1.7.59

```
import boto3

s3 = boto3.client('s3')
r = s3.select_object_content(
    Bucket="bucket",
    Key="file.json",
    ExpressionType='SQL',
    Expression="select * from s3object S3Object AS s",
    InputSerialization = {
                            'JSON': {
                            'Type': 'LINES'
                            }
                        },
    OutputSerialization = { 'JSON': { 'RecordDelimiter': ',' } },
)


for event in r['Payload']:
    if 'Records' in event:
        records = event['Records']['Payload'].decode('utf-8')
        print(records)
    elif 'Stats' in event:
        statsDetails = event['Stats']['Details']
        print("Stats details bytesScanned: ")
        print(statsDetails['BytesScanned'])
        print("Stats details bytesProcessed: ")
        print(statsDetails['BytesProcessed'])
```

After run my code I'm getting the error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "C:/Users/a_urrego/PycharmProjects/DW_FlightHub/S3Select.py", line 48,
>   in 
>       OutputSerialization = { 'JSON': { 'RecordDelimiter': ',' } },   File
>   "C:\Users\a_urrego\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\botocore\client.py",
>   line 314, in _api_call
>       return self._make_api_call(operation_name, kwargs)   File "C:\Users\a_urrego\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\botocore\client.py",
>   line 612, in _make_api_call
>       raise error_class(parsed_response, operation_name) botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred
>   (ParseUnexpectedToken) when calling the SelectObjectContent operation:
>   Unexpected token found AS:as at line 1, column 33.
>
> Process finished with exit code 1

Comment: `Expression="select * from s3object"` - this much is sufficient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like the SQL expression you're passing is invalid:

```
"select * from s3object S3Object AS s"
```

general SQL syntax will be

```
"SELECT <columns | *> FROM <table> <alias>"
```

but it looks like you've duplicated a table name or something there.  Upper casing on the SQL statements is optional, but I tend to like it.

I haven't used this feature of boto3, but this seems to be the issue after 3 minutes of googling and reading the error message.

[Edit]

Updated my template above after realizing a typo.  Also worth noting that a table alias is unnecessary in this use case as it's a very simple SELECT statement.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the AS also, it will raise another error, bellow will be enough:

```
select * from s3object S3Object
```